# Java Hashtable question

Tags: java

My code returns entrySet() as expected if called from within its own class. However if i call it via  a getter method in Main it returns an empty table. Why?

```
class Results
{
    Hashtable<String, Double> langScores ;

    public Results()
    {
        langScores = new Hashtable<String, Double>() ;
    }

    public void addScores(double pL1, double pL2, double pL3)
    {
        langScores.put("English", pL1 ) ;
        langScores.put("French", pL2 ) ;
        langScores.put("German", pL3 ) ;
        System.out.println(langScores.entrySet()) ;
    }

    public Set<Map.Entry<String, Double>> getWinner()
    {
        return langScores.entrySet() ;
    }
}
```

MAIN:

```
class LanguageIdentifier 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Results winner = new Results() ;

        AnalyseText analyse = new AnalyseText() ; //addScores called from this class

        analyse.analyseText() ;
        System.out.println(winner.getWinner()) ;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
[German=0.0040, French=0.0030, English=0.02] // print statement within Results class works

[] // print statement within Main class prints empty table !?
```

Comment: Where do you call addScores() in your MAIN snippet?

Comment: addScores is called from AnalyseText class and works correctly given that i get a filled table back. Also note that the print statement in Result class is after the add statements to show that htese work.

Comment: But you don't pass the Results to the AnalyseText class. You are calling addScores() on a different object to the one that on which you're calling getWinner().

Comment: yes indeed, i realise that now. must think of a way of making the hashtable object independant, if there is such a thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main you didn't put any scores in winner (using `addScores`), so it's still empty.

Adding the line `winner.addScores(1, 2, 3);` fixed it for me.

As sjr mentioned, and according to your edit, you don't pass a reference to the `Results` object to the `analyse` object in creation, change the `AnalyseText` constructor to receive `Results` object as a parameter, and set the private `Result` reference of `TextAnalyser` to this object:

```
Results winner;
public TextAnalyser(Results winner)
{
    this.winner = winner;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i was not thinking in OO terms and thought the Hashtable langScores  would be Object independant

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the instance of `Results` in the `main` method is diferent as the instance in `AnalyseText` object.

This is OO basic.